# Adding a brush to an existing custom brush library in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an existing custom brush library I created in Illustrator (CS5).  I just created a new brush that I would like to add to this existing library.  How can I do this?
Drag and drop does not work.  There is no fly-out on the custom brush library panel allowing me to add a new brush.  I can't overwrite the existing custom brush library like I can in Photoshop.

Is there a simple way to do this or am I stuck having to recreate the entire library again in the default brush panel just to add one more?

Answer (score 6):

Navigate to the library file in your operating system.

Open the library file just like you would any other illustrator file.

Add your brush. Save and close.

Then when you choose the Library from the Brush Panel, the new brush will be part of the library.

This same procedure goes for all Library files - swatches, styles, brushes, symbols etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped.