# how to add new brush in existing user defined brush library in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

I have created one Brush library (several brushes) in Illustrator, named 'my brushes', and saved it. now I want to add another new brush to 'my brushes' but I can't. It does not allow me to drag the new brush there.

Is there any way I can drag the new brush and drop it in the saved brush library or do I have to create a new brush list every time?

Thank you. [image]

Comment: Does this answer? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10585/adding-a-brush-to-an-existing-custom-brush-library-in-illustrator

Comment: Also, Adobe docs don't mention anything about adding new brushes to existing libraries.

Comment: Hello, Vikas. Thank you.

Comment: It didnt work, Illustrator Crushed.

Comment: I tried and it works fine. How did you do it?

Comment: oh my god, now it worked.

Comment: I was doing it wrong. but later I figured it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah it should. Basically, you create a new library and save it. Then open it from its location in drive, it will be a separate document. So you add a new brush in it and press Control + S to save it. Then close this document. Close your main document too (not needed I think, but still I'd tend to do). Then open your main document again and you'll see the new brush in your library.

Comment: yes yes, I am so happy I can do it. Thank you <3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127581/discussion-between-suraiya-abedin-and-vikas).